# Laravel - Access a value from DB::table()->insert

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building an Insert query using [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) and I wonder whether it is possible to use a value to-be-inserted in another value.

Here is an example, not accurate for my situation but explains well:

```
DB::table('debts')->insert([

    'name' => $faker->company,

    'debt' =>  $faker->randomFloat($nbMaxDecimals = 2, $min = 20000, $max = 10000000),

    'debt_paid' => 'debt' /  rand ( 2 , 8 ),

    'notes' => $faker->paragraph($nbSentences = 3, $variableNbSentences = true),

]);
```

As you can see, in the row of `debt_paid` I want to access the value of `'debt'` that was randomly defined a row above. This is because `debt_paid` needs to be logical and without the value of `debt` it might be non-sense.

I know that defining 'debt' as a variable before the insert would solve it, but I wonder whether there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

So do that outside the insert

```
$dbt = $faker->randomFloat($nbMaxDecimals = 2, $min = 20000, $max = 10000000);

DB::table('debts')->insert([
    'name' => $faker->company,
    'debt' =>  $dbt,
    'debt_paid' => $dbt /  rand ( 2 , 8 ),
    'notes' => $faker->paragraph($nbSentences = 3, $variableNbSentences = true),
]);
```